# Button.setTextPosition(Label.LEFT); render wrong

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

My NetBeans recently updated new CodenameOne plugin and it looks like the Button.setTextPosition(Label.LEFT); renders wrong position of the icon on Android and iOS, the icon always overlaps with the text. It still renders with the simulator correctly and the function still renders with Label.RIGHT, Label.TOP and Label.BOTTOM parameters correctly. Do you have any idea?

Thanks,
William

Comment: I've seen reports of this but was unable to reproduce this myself. Can you provide a code snippet that reproduces the issue and ideally some screenshots?

Comment: I think the key is I don't use theme in my app. You can create a simple test app without use theme, and set layout to this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); and add buttons with text and icon. The screenshot here [link](http://s19.postimg.org/wqvkfn1f7/Screenshot_2016_01_03_01_08_21.png). You can see the first and fifth one.

Answer (score 1):

I see the issue there, its a regression that only occurs with smaller icons since the width of the icon is used instead of the width of the text only in the case of left aligned text which is more rare.

We'll fix this in the next server update.

Answer (score 1):

Shai, I think the problem is that the icon was scaled to font.getHeight() of the button.

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Test", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Font font = new Button("Test").getUnselectedStyle().getFont();
    Image t = pictures.getImage("Play.png").scaled(font.getHeight(), font.getHeight());
    hi.add(b(Button.LEFT, " Left 123", t))
            .add(b(Button.RIGHT, " Right ", t))
            .add(b(Button.TOP, " Top ", t))
            .add(b(Button.BOTTOM, " Bottom ", t));
    hi.add(b(Button.LEFT, " Left ", t))
            .add(b(Button.RIGHT, " Right ", t))
            .add(b(Button.TOP, " Top ", t))
            .add(b(Button.BOTTOM, " Bottom ", t));
    hi.show();
}

private Button b(int pos, String txt, Image t) {
    Button btn = new Button(txt, t);
    btn.setTextPosition(pos);
    return btn;
}
```

Here is the screenshots:

Simulator:

[image: Simulator's screenshot]

Nexus (android):

[image: Nexus's screenshot]

Comment: You should edit the question to provide details never post another "answer" to provide further details. You might get moderated down for something like that. Thanks for the details though see my revised answer.